# angular ui-router - nested controller - parent controller is initiated twice if child controller is in the same state

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
        'main': {
            templateUrl: './main.html',
            controller: 'mainController'
        },
        'parent@home': {
            templateUrl: './parent.html',
            controller: 'parentController'
        },
        'child@home':{
            templateUrl: './child.html',
            controller: 'childController'
        },
        'otherPage@home': {
            templateUrl: './other-page.html',
            controller: 'otherController'
        }
    }
})
```

In parent.html i have the child view . Basically the parent controller (parentController) is initiated twice in this setup. If i remove the child@home state, the parentController is initiated only once. What am i doing wrong, is there a better way to define these states?

### index.html

```
<div class="maincontent" ui-view="main"></div>
```

### main.html

```
<div class="maincontent container-fluid" ui-view="parent"></div>
<div class="maincontent container-fluid" ui-view="otherPage"></div>
```

### parent.html

```
<div ui-view="child"></div>
```

Comment: you are not defining any states!

Comment: Maybe you can show your template markup? That would give someone a better idea/understanding of your issue

Comment: ragingprodigy, i have added the template markups, let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redefine the state like this:

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    views: {
        '': {
            templateUrl: './main.html',
            controller: 'mainController'
        },
        'parent@home': {
            templateUrl: './parent.html',
            controller: 'parentController'
        },
        'child@home':{
            templateUrl: './child.html',
            controller: 'childController'
        },
        'otherPage@home': {
            templateUrl: './other-page.html',
            controller: 'otherController'
        }
    }
})
```

Form my understanding, the view with the empty key would be loaded as the default for the home state.

Done this way, your `main.html` template would then contain pointers to other `ui-views` as you've done with `parent` and `otherPage`.

I've not been able to test this because I'm not on my dev PC but I think it should work because it's the format followed in a couple of my AngularJS projects.

Comment: you are suggesting remove the state name for main and have it as ''? this doesn't help, in fact thats how i started off with.

Comment: Check out this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/yRgAlf6sGjB9fIjmnTg9?p=preview